# ¿Azure Portal es SaaS, PaaS o IaaS?

Tags: azure, cloud

Al principio pensaba que era PaaS, pero al entender mucho mejor estos conceptos tengo dudas. Pienso que es SaaS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la respuesta a mi duda dentro de la documentación oficial, y efectivamente es SaaS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]